# how can i only use ng-repeat for fill data in html ,not repeat Html's elements?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, semantic-ui

I want to have an iterative moving over an array of users , and fill every `td` with a unique user in array, but I dont want to repeat and produce new html code in every `ng-repeat`'s step.

I just want have a moving on the td's and for each one , put a user inside that `td`.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="fill">
<head>
<?php include "includes/head.php" ?> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
        var fill=angular.module("fill",[]);
            fill.controller("fillTable",function($scope){
            $scope.users=[  {name:"jack"},
                            {name:"joe"},
                            {name:"alen"},
                            {name:"mina"},
                            {name:"mari"},
                            {name:"karen"}
                        ];
        });
    })()
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table ng-controller="fillTable" border=1>
        <tbody  ng-repeat="user in users">
            <tr>
                <td>user 1:{{user.name}}</td>
                <td>user 2:{{user.name}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>user 3:{{user.name}}</td>
                <td>user 4:{{user.name}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>user 5:{{user.name}}</td>
                <td>user 6:{{user.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>    
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

actually, i have a grid with four columns that i created it by semantic-ui-grid. 
now i want to read many articles from  dataBase's tables then i have puting  that datas inside grid's columns.{like a 'pinterest style' page } [a pic for more explain , please see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhWgc.png)

Comment: Use any data table plugin...

Comment: or create a method with returns your desired html code: generateHtml()... the ng-repeat has a well defined purpose, to repeat the html tags.

Comment: thanks for your view. is  any other angular directives that have a movement over elements and do something for us ?and why i get 2 negativs mark ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create pairs in controller:

```
$scope.users = [
 {name:"jack"},
 {name:"joe"},
 {name:"alen"},
 {name:"mina"},
 {name:"mari"},
 {name:"karen"}
];
$scope.pairs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i+=2) {
  $scope.users[i].index = i+1;
  if ($scope.users[i+1]) {
    $scope.users[i+1].index = i+2;
    $scope.pairs.push([$scope.users[i], $scope.users[i+1]]);
  } else {
    $scope.pairs.push([$scope.users[i]]);
  }
}
```

and iterate over pairs:

```
<table ng-controller="fillTable" border=1>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="pair in pairs">
            <td ng-repeat="user in pair">user {{user.index}}:{{user.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

Comment: thanks too much. it works . and create a table with 2 columns and fill every td with diffrent user . but keep in mind i dont want create new html tag in every ng-repeat step .thanks again.

Comment: @MohsenRezaei Don't forget to mark the question if it solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other workaround than to make a special array containing user pairs :

```
$scope.$watch('users', function() {
   $scope.userPairs = [];
   for (var i=0;i<$scope.users.length;i=i+2) {
      $scope.userPairs.push({  
        name1 : $scope.users[i].name, 
        name2 : $scope.users[i+1].name
      })
   }     
})
```

also use `ng-repeat` properly (you want to iterate over `<tr>`'s not `<tbody>`'s :

```
<table border=1>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in userPairs">
            <td>user 1:{{user.name1 }}</td>
            <td>user 2:{{user.name2 }}</td>  
        </tr> 
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/yK3F9US4XuS6sPnVv0Dd?p=preview**

Answer (score -1):

```
<table ng-controller="fillTable" border=1>
    <tbody  ng-repeat="user in users track by $index">
        <tr>
            <td>user 1:{{users[$index].name}}</td>
            <td>user 2:{{users[$index+1].name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>user 3:{{users[$index+2].name}}</td>
            <td>user 4:{{users[$index+3].name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>user 5:{{users[$index+4].name}}</td>
            <td>user 6:{{users[$index+5].name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

Comment: This will create 6 tbody elements that are the same.

Comment: who ever down vote do you got what the question clear?  :D

Comment: thanks alot . it has produce too  much rows more than i want., i try with users[$index++] unfortunatly it didn't work too. thanks again .

Comment: great ! i hope you got the concept of track by $index and you may use it as you want. I wonder, one should never look for ready to use code rather understand the concept.